# Por que devemos interromper a corrente de Promises em funções recursivas no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promises

Vou exemplificar com códigos.

Tenho uma função assíncrona chamada `delay` que recebe um tempo em segundos e que retorna uma *Promise*. Ela serve para prover um tempo de espera em segundos:

```js
// padrão de 1 segundo
function delay (time = 1) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, time * 1_000) // resolve depois de X segundos
  })
}
```

Agora vou criar uma função relógio `clock` que irá exibir a hora local ( `toLocaleTimeString`) a cada tempo de atraso (`time`) definido na função `delay`, e quando esta for resolvida, irei exibir um log no console da hora atual. Depois irei recursivamente invocar a função `clock` e retorná-la:

```js
function clock () {
  return delay(1).then(() => {
    // exibe a hora
    console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString()) 

    // inicia a recursão
    return clock() 
  })
}
```

Vamos executar o nosso relógio:

```js
// padrão de 1 segundo
function delay (time = 1) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, time * 1_000) // resolve depois de X segundos
  })
}

function clock () {
  return delay(1).then(() => {
    // exibe a hora
    console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString()) 

    // inicia a recursão
    return clock() 
  })
}

// bootstrap
clock()
```

Usando `async/await`:

```js
// padrão de 1 segundo
function delay (time = 1) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, time * 1_000) // resolve depois de X segundos
  })
}

async function clock () {
  await delay(1)
  
  // exibe a hora
  console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString()) 
  
  // inicia a recursão
  return clock() 
}

// bootstrap
clock()
```

Repare que em ambos os casos, o código funciona normalmente e o relógio mostra a hora atualizada a cada segundo. Entretanto,  o fato de eu ter uma função que retorna uma *Promise* (retorna `delay` e esta retorna um objeto `Promise`) e esta *Promise* ativa a recursão, gera uma corrente de *Promises*. **Isto deve ser evitado!**

- Por que?
- Qual problema eu resolvo ao interromper a corrente de *Promises* causada pela recursão em `clock`?

Comment: Não encontrei nada relacionado. Se vc encontrou, fique a vontade para sinalizar. Acho que a pergunta pode contribuir com a comunidade :)

Comment: eu achei a pergunta bem interessante, especialmente pelos exemplos +1

Comment: Eu realmente nunca vi isso, mas suspeito que você já sabe a resposta. Quero um spoiler! :D Suponho que seja por causa do acúmulo gradual de memória na _call stack_ (testei aqui e meio que aconteceu isso), mas não tenho certeza... De todo modo, não há ganho nenhum em se utilizar recursão aí. Um simples `while` já resolveria.

Comment: @LuizFelipe é [isso](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec/issues/179) mesmo. Tem haver com memory leak

Comment: Como diz o Maniero, funcionar é diferente de estar certo. Eu questiono a necessidade de se utilizar recursão no caso da pergunta, mas entendo que foi um exemplo para situar o problema. Eu sigo a premissa de que, como as principais engines de JavaScript nem sequer realizam TCO, quase nunca realmente vale a pena utilizar recursão em JavaScript. E como há a equivalência entre recursão e laços "comuns", estes são sempre preferíveis quando o mínimo de performance (nesse caso principalmente economia de memória) é um fator importante.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você realmente tem memória vazando aí, mas o motivo principal não é a estrutura recursiva – que neste caso é assíncrona e indireta. A raiz do problema é o comportamento do método `then` das promessas.

Simplificando um pouco o seu código:

```
function clock () {
    console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString())
    return delay(1).then(clock)
}
```

Você sabe que poderia encadear outro `then` no final se quisesse. Isso funciona porque o `then` retorna outra promessa. O estado dessa promessa depende do retorno da função passada ao `then` – que é o manipulador de um evento disparado quando  `delay(1)` for resolvida. A promessa retornada pelo `then` será criada já resolvida se a função retornar um valor qualquer (inclusive `undefined`), ou uma promessa resolvida. A mesma lógica vale para promessas rejeitadas. Mas se a função retornar uma promessa pendente, o `then` retorna uma nova promessa também pendente, e que só será resolvida após a solução dessa promessa original.

Resumindo esse mecanismo todo: cada execução de `clock` cria uma nova promessa, e adia a resolução do `then` para a execução seguinte. E essa para a próxima, sucessivamente e infinitamente. A cadeia de promessas que você citou é um problema porque ela nunca será resolvida.

Isso já indica a solução: basta que `clock` não retorne uma promessa pendente. Isso porém não te impede de continuar encadeando as chamadas. A versão a seguir já não vaza mais memória:

```
function clock () {
    console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString())
    delay(1).then(clock)

    // Pode retornar qualquer coisa, ou pode omitir o return.
    // Omitir o return equivale a `return undefined`.
    // Não pode retornar a promessa gerada logo acima, ou outra que dependa dela
}
```